# Plotting Wind Barb and Wind Speed for multiple iterations

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, netcdf, contourf

I have 2 netcdf files: -
uwnd.10m.mon.ltm.nc and vwnd.10m.mon.ltm.nc

I have to do wind barb plot of "Long Term Mean Monthly Mean of Winds".
I also have to plot Wind Speed with contour fill.
The plot is to be carried out 12 times.

I have attached a demo Image of how I need the desired output to look like for one iteration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyip2.jpg)

I have tried using the barb() along with contourf(), however i am getting the below output: -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y202Y.jpg)

I am new to python and maps, so if somebody can help me with the code, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a shorter code sample. We need to know what like threw error, preferably with the full error. Irrelevant code, such as print statements should also be removed

Comment: I have modified the question for easy understanding of what exactly I want the output to look like. Request please let me know if anyone has any idea regarding this type of plots. Thank you.